# How to transform a set of complex numbers by applying the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

I have a set of complex numbers, 
$S = \left\{ z \in C 1 \leq \lvert z \rvert \leq 2, \frac{\pi}{4} \leq 
\lvert arg(z) \rvert \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \right\}$.
How do I determine the subset $ f(S) = \frac{1}{z^2} $?

Comment: Step one is to know how to write out the problem clearly, instead of "$f(S) = 1/z^2$", it should be "$f(S)$, where $f(z) = \frac1{z^2}$". Secondly, what are your thoughts? What's the hang-up - is $S$ too complicated? is $f$ too complicated?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I dont know how to input the set into the function to get f(S).

Comment: The definition of "function of a set" $f(A)$ is $\{f(a) : a\in A\}$ and it is called the image of $A$ under $f$

Comment: I understand the definition of the set, and what everything means in that sense, but I don't know how to get the subset f(S). e.g. Do i just but z=1 into 1/z^2 then get 1 again? Do I put arg(z)=pi/4 and get pi/2?

Comment: Well you do everything with intention and the ability to prove it. Whether or not you call that "just" doing, I don't know. But for starters, if you want to claim that $f(A) = B$, where $B$ is the set you are guessing, then you can start by showing that $f(A) \subset B$ i.e. $z\in f(A) \implies z\in B$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider what this function does to (1) rays from the origin, and (2) circles around the origin.

To do this, look at $f(r e^{i\theta_0})$ as $r$ varies (with $\theta_0$ fixed), and at $f(r_0e^{i\theta})$ as $\theta$ varies (with $r_0$ fixed).

Note that $f(re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{r^2}e^{i(-2\theta)}$.